# How to fix error using equalsIgnorecase in java netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I am building java project in inventory management. following is the code i used for inserting color in database using equalsIgnorecase but it continuous showing Already exist. Please some one fix my code.
thanks

```
private void btnAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        if(txtNewColor.getText().equals(""))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Fields should not be empty");
        }
        else
        {

            try {

                String c = txtNewColor.getText();
                ps =DbConnection.cn.prepareStatement("Select Color from color_details");
                rs = ps.executeQuery();
                int color = 0;
                while (rs.next())
                {
                    String cl= rs.getString("Color");
                    if(cl.equalsIgnoreCase(cl));

                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Aready Exist");
                        txtNewColor.setText("");
                        color=1;
                    }
                }

                if (color==0)
                {

                    String strdata="Insert into color_details (Color)values(?)";
                    ps=DbConnection.cn.prepareStatement(strdata);

                    ps.setString(1, txtNewColor.getText());
                    ps.execute();

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "New Color Added Successfully");
                    cleartext();

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            }
        }
        refreshTable();

        }
```

Comment: `cl.equalsIgnoreCase(cl)`??

Comment: Why do you want to compare two same Strings?

Comment: `if(cl.equalsIgnoreCase(cl));` semicolon

Comment: thats my mistake to compare same string but now i use cl.equalsIgnoreCase(c) but the result is same.

Answer (score 1):

Try change `if(cl.equalsIgnoreCase(cl));` to `if(c.equalsIgnoreCase(cl))`

Had not spotted the semi-colon at the end of your if statement

Comment: Why does an if have a semicolon? It doesn't execute the next statements.

Comment: Oversight, thats very true

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing the same String again. So It always results in a `true`, also the `;` will skip even if they match. Remove it.

```
 String c = txtNewColor.getText();
                ps =DbConnection.cn.prepareStatement("Select Color from color_details");
                rs = ps.executeQuery();
                int color = 0;
                while (rs.next())
                {
                    String cl= rs.getString("Color");
                    if(cl.equalsIgnoreCase(c))
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Aready Exist");
                        txtNewColor.setText("");
                        color=1;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: i tried this your correction but it still showing already exists multiple time. is there any other way to compare uppercase & lower case

Answer (score 1):

You used same two strings to compare. so change `c.equalsIgnoreCase(c1)`. Also make sure you have removed trailing spaces when getting input from text fields. it may makes your comparison fail.

```
String c = txtNewColor.getText().trim();
```

Remove the semi colon after if clause
`if(cl.equalsIgnoreCase(cl));` ---> `if(cl.equalsIgnoreCase(cl))`

Comment: can you print all the comparison list and show it. System.out.println(c+"  "+c1);

Comment: when i use if(c.equals(cl)) it works fine but doesnt compare cases, i tried different ways but same result :(

Comment: can you give a simple example that fails. use system.out.println to get comparisons

Comment: did tried after removing semicolan in the if clause

Comment: i forgot how to use system.out.println and ya i remove semicolan, same code works for my friend but it didnt work for me. i can send u java file if u want

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zglw8tplmn7ywab/Stocks.java?dl=0
Link to java file. someone plz solve this error.
Thanks